# How to get the value of selected row using radiobutton in gridview in a button click

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radio-button

i need to get the value of the selected row of radiobutton in the gridview. the selected value is assigned to a textbox. my code is

```
 protected void lnBTNDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              GridViewRow gvRow = grdEventDetails.SelectedRow;
              txtEventId.Text = gvRow.Cells[0].Text;

          }
```

the problem is the gvRow value is assigned as null .

the linkbutton is not inside gridview. the gridview n linkbutton and the textbox are inside the user controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void lnBTNDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grdEventDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        RadioButton rb = (grdEventDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("grdRdo")) as RadioButton;
        if (rb.Checked == true)
        {
            txtEventId.Text = grdEventDetails.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
        }
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always get the `GridViewRow` via the sender's [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx):

```
protected void lnBTNDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton  lnBTNDone = (LinkButton)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lnBTNDone.NamingContainer;
    txtEventId.Text = row.Cells[0].Text;
}
```

Assuming that the `LinkButton` is in the selected row.

Btw, i'm yet not sure why `SelectedRow` is null there, maybe because the GridView's `SelectedIndexChanged` event is triggered after the LinkButton's click event.

Comment: getting this error Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.usercontrols_usc_eventidparameter_ascx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.

Comment: @kk1076: Then my assumption what incorrect. I thought the LinkButton was in the GridView. Then you should tell us where the linkbutton is located and how you are selecteing the row in the gridview.

Comment: the link button is not inside the gridview. but gridview, textbox and the link button are placed in user control page

Comment: How are you selecting the GridView's row and are you databinding the GridView only `if(!IsPostBack)`(what would be the correct way)?

Comment: i have binded the gridview in filter button click not in the pageload event